# I am trying to add A JComboBox in a JTable Cell,

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I am trying to add a `JComboBox` in a `JTable` cell.
After addding the JComboBox in the row vector

```
Vector rown=new Vector();
rown.add(comboBox1);
```

and run my GUI, the table shows:

```
javax.swing.JComboBox[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777536,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=VALUE_ONE
```

Rather than `VALUE_ONE` in a `JComboBox`.

Where Am I going wrong?

Comment: See [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). You don't have to add the combo box to the table model but provide a proper cell editor/renderer instead.

Comment: Also [*Using a Combo Box as an Editor*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox).

Answer (score 0):

```
TableColumn comboCol1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
comboCol1.setCellEditor(new CustomComboBoxEditor());

public class CustomComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
private DefaultComboBoxModel model;

public CustomComboBoxEditor() {
   super(new JComboBox());
   this.model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)((JComboBox)getComponent()).getModel();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    model.addElement(orderList.get(i));
 } 


   return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Why subclassing DefaultCellEditor? There's a [convenience class constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#DefaultCellEditor-javax.swing.JComboBox-) that takes a JComboBox as argument so we don't have to subclass at all.